# Swift 4.2 way of getting URLError.UnderlyingCocoaError

Tags: swift, swift4, swift4.2

I'm attempting to find the updated version of this Error.

I have an if statement calling

```
if case let URLError.UnderlyingCocoaError(request, _, _, _) = error {...}
```

Seems this functionality has been lost since Swift 2.

How does one do this in Swift 4.2?

Comment: Have you checked the `URLError`'s `errorUserInfo` dictionary?